# Prelude and Premiere Workflow with DSLR and External Audio

Tags: premiere, audio, dslr

This is a little long, but hopefully will make sense...

I am shooting with a GH4 to record interviews and cuts the videos into 4GB segments. I'm recording the audio with a Zoom (external recorder). So I end up with a multiple video files with in-camera audio (which I use just for syncing) but one large .wav file from the recorder.

Here's the issue. I want to be able to sync the video but also use proxy videos since I'm recording at 4K (but producing 1080p). Here are the options as I see them but maybe something I'm missing:

- Concatenate the videos so that I can sync the .wav file but then I lose the ability to use proxy videos (I'd have to re-encode before editing)
- Edit with proxy videos but then syncing and splitting the audio to the multiple videos becomes really difficult.
- Concatenate without reencoding so i can sync the .wav files, but then cut it up into manageable chunks for editing. But the multiple encoding it concerns me.

I'm using Prelude to log my footage, then Premiere to edit it.

Is there a senseable answer I'm missing? I hate all three options.

Comment: How are you synching the audio? I synch in Premiere using the audio from the clips, and often have just one audio file for lots of video files. Premiere deals with this situation fine, without having to split the audio track.

Comment: Great to know. That would solve it all! Let me try it!

Comment: It seems that when it does this it pads it with black video. Is this what you're seeing? I was hoping it would sync the audio and keep the video the same time.

Comment: Yes, where the audio starts before or ends after the video you won't see any video so the screen will be blank. This isn't usually a problem when you're editing, just set your in and out points as normal.